# Bootstrap drop down throwing itself to the right of my menu

Tags: menu, dropdown

hoping one of you will be able to help!

I'm currently building a website and having to fumble through code a bit using Bootstrap, im coming to the closing end of finalising it however ive hit an issue where one of my drop down menus fire off to the right when clicked, i've done a bit of googling and trying to mess about with the code but i cant get it to sit right.

HTML is as follows

```
        <div class="col-12">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-xs">About Us</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-xs" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Programmes
                </button>

                <div class="btn-group">
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Private</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Veteran</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Young Adult</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sponsor</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Volunteer</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fundraise</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-xs" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Media
                </button>

                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pictures</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Blog</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Newsletter</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-xs">Donate</button>
    </div>
```

Nothing has been changed in the Bootstrap CSS other than the colours of the buttons themselves

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine you just need to wrap `div` having class of `btn-group` above Programms button tag

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="col-12">
  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-xs">About Us</button>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-xs" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Programmes
        </button>


        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Private</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Veteran</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Young Adult</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sponsor</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Volunteer</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fundraise</a>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-xs" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Media
        </button>

        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pictures</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Blog</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Newsletter</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-xs">Donate</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Then can you mark this post as an answer if it helps you.